# OpenIDConnect code flow and Google

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect

I'm trying to use openID connect to authenticate against google using the code flow.

I'm sending an auth request to google like

```
 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?   client_id=***.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44321%2fAccount%2fConfirmLogin&
response_mode=form_post&
response_type=code&
scope=openid+email+profile&
state=STUFF
nonce=A_NONCE
```

and I get back a GET response

```
GET https://localhost:44321/Account/ConfirmLogin?state=STUFF&
code=Some letters&
authuser=0&
hd=my app domain&
session_state=HEX&
prompt=none
```

According to the spec : http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthResponse

> When using the Authorization Code Flow, the Authorization Response **MUST** return the parameters defined in Section 4.1.2 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] by adding them as query parameters to the redirect_uri specified in the Authorization Request using the *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* format, **unless a different Response Mode was specified**.

From my reading of the spec this means google should return a POST to my server not a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for the `form_post` response mode as defined in http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html is optional and it is not supported by Google. Hence the parameter is ignored.

Comment: I get that part but the OIC spec seems to contradict this in this case.

Comment: yeah, the spec also says to ignore unknown parameters